# Select all cells with values in A column and text to Columns with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

my task is:

1) Select all cells in A row which contain values (done).
2) Text to Columns - example value 2017.01.01

```
Sub selectAndToColumns()
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A1:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select
'2nd step
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range(A1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :=".", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1))
End Sub
```

1 step is ok, but how can I use my selection instead of Range(A1) in 2nd step? Can I make a variable and how?

Comment: What do you mean with `my selection`?

Comment: I understand your problem.... *TextToColumns* will work on an **entire** column rather than some set of cells within that column.

Comment: I agree that no need in step 1 - i need just select the whole column, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure about your requirements, but this will perform the TextToColumns without selecting anything (You can still change the destination to wherever you want the resulting data to be placed, you can do this by specifying a range or even using a variable where your range is stored):

```
Sub selectAndToColumns()
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A1:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :=".", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1))
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to replace your destination with a variable instead of Range("A1") then something like below will work:

```
Sub selectAndToColumns()
    Dim DestinationRange As String
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    DestinationRange = "D1"
    MsgBox DestinationRange
    Range("A1:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).TextToColumns Destination:=Range(DestinationRange), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :=".", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I have understood your question properly, but if you just want to select Column A and paste it as values, I would use:

```
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
     :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Selecting working even in my macro but i needed text to column after. Thanks for your answer anyway.